# How to get action.params from saga

Tags: javascript, redux, state, redux-saga

I am using `redux-saga`. In the code `yield* ReduxSaga.takeEvery('MY_ACTION', updatePorts);` how can I access the `action` to get its fields.

For example I have an action creator:

```
function status(){
  type: 'MY_ACTION',
  status: true
}
```

How can I access `action.status` from my saga? Or do I have to access data only via `getState()` and [select](https://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/api/index.html#selectselector-args)?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
const actionCreator=()=>({
  type: 'MY_ACTION',
  status:true
})

 function* updatePorts(action) {
  console.log(action.status)
}

function* watchUpdatePorts() {
  yield* takeEvery('MY_ACTION', updatePorts)
}
```

https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/tree/master/docs/api#takeeverypattern-saga-args

Comment: You are awesome. It's working. Can you please post a link to documentation. I could have found it.

Comment: Working for me. Awesome dude!

Answer (score 2):

```
const actionCreator = () => ({
  type: 'MY_ACTION',
  status: true
})

function* updatePorts() {
  while (true) {
      const { status } = take('MY_ACTION');
      // ...
  }

}
```

You could also do something like this. The redux-saga docs have a nice explanation on the advantages:

> Using take has a subtle impact on how we write our code. In the case of takeEvery the invoked tasks have no control on when they'll be called. They will be invoked again and again on each matching action. They also have no control on when to stop the observation.
>
> In the case of take the control is inverted. Instead of the actions
> being pushed to the handler tasks, the Saga is pulling the action by
> itself. It looks as if the Saga is performing a normal function call
> action = getNextAction() which will resolve when the action is
> dispatched.

read more here: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/FutureActions.html

Answer (score 0):

Normally you may have a root saga or index saga and in that you can have a init generator with yield all to look like below:

```
//in your action creator
const actionCreator = () => ({
    type: 'MY_ACTION1',
    status: true
});
//in your saga file, you will receive 'action' and then you can destructure it to status if you want.
function* updateDataForAction1({ status }) {
    //use value of status 
}
//in your root saga file
export function* watchInit() {
    yield all([
        takeEvery('MY_ACTION1', updateDataForAction1),
        takeEvery('MY_ACTION2', updateDataForAction2),
        takeEvery('MY_ACTION3', updateDataForAction3),
    ]);
}
```